# Django - создание представления в модели

Tags: python, django, postgresql, view

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в модели (`models.py`) Django создать Представление (View).

Например,

```sql
CREATE VIEW mscd_gov.journal_select
AS

SELECT
    mscd_gov.journal.*,
    json_agg(duty_shift) AS duty_shift
FROM
    mscd_gov.journal
        LEFT JOIN mscd_gov.duty_shift ON duty_shift.uuid = journal.uuid_duty_shift
GROUP BY mscd_gov.journal.uuid;
-- ddl-end --
COMMENT ON VIEW mscd_gov.journal_select IS E'Представление журнала';
```

За ссылки на материалы и пример кода буду очень благодарен!

Спасибо!

P.S. БД Postgresql

Comment: Возможно это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110785/django-model-for-a-postgres-view

Comment: В любом случае, вы всегда можете использовтаь RawSQL. На сколько помню, не встречал  функционала, что вам нужен в документации Django

Comment: Вот и я его никак не найду

Comment: ```from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL```

Answer (score 0):

Вот [статья](https://resources.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/) в которой можно найти ответы по представлениям в Django ORM.